# Using Javascript to Send 1 GET Request And 2 POST Requests in a Infinite Loop

Tags: javascript

I am not very familiar with JavaScript, but hoping this is possible.

I need the script to do 3 things:

1. Send a GET request to `https://example.com/test.php` which replies back with this JSON:  `[{"user_id":"12345","email":"test@test.com","status":"active"}]`
2. Send a POST request to `https://example.com/checker.php` with these parameters `action=testing&email=test@test.com&status=active` - the second two parameters are retrieved from the step above.  Responses to this post request  will vary.
3. Send a POST request to `https://example.com/verified.php` with these parameter `response=RESPONSE-FROM-STEP-2-HERE`.

And I need it to repeat all 3 steps  in an infinite loop for as long as the visitor is on the page (should automatically start as soon as the page is loaded).

It looks like in JavaScript I can use `xhttp.open` for both GET and POST requests.  What I'm unsure about is how to then use those responses in steps 2 and 3.

Comment: Do you want to send them one after the other, where you wait for the GET to finish and then fire the first POST?  Also, your subsequent GET responses might pull from cache instead of hitting the server.

Comment: Yes, I do want to send one after another.  It's okay if I run into issues with cache.

Comment: Check out the documentation for ```fetch()``` as a starting point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you think something like this will be useful? you can also use await. But this should give you an idea.

```
var getTest = () => new Promise((res, rej) => {
  console.log('request getUsersId');
  return res([{"user_id":"12345","email":"test@test.com","status":"active"}]);
});


var postChecker = (requestParams) => new Promise((res, rej) => {
  console.log('request postChecker' + JSON.stringify(requestParams));
  return res({"step2response": "RandomResponse"})
});

var postVerified = (requestParams) => new Promise((res, rej) => {
    console.log('request postVerified' + JSON.stringify(requestParams));
    return res({"step3Response": "step3Response"})
  });


getTest().then((response)=>{
    postChecker(response).then((response)=>{
        postVerified(response);
    })
})
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function step1() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log(1)
            resolve(1)
        }, 1000)
    })
}
function step2() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log(2)
            resolve(2)
        }, 500)
    })
}
function step3() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log(3)
            resolve(3)
        }, 200)
    })
}

step1().then(data1 => {
    step2().then(data2 => {
        step3().then(data3 => {
            console.log(data1, data2, data3)
        })
    })
})
```

Comment: Please read... "What I'm unsure about is how to then use those responses in steps 2 and 3."